# PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler in JBoss EAP 7.3 is not deleting old logs

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I'm using **periodic-size-rotating-file-handler** to only keep the most recent log files according to this configuration;

```
<periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
  <formatter>
    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
  </formatter>
  <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
  <rotate-size value="10k"/>
  <max-backup-index value="5"/>
  <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <append value="true"/>
</periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
```

What I expect is that it will create a new log file whenever the current one exceeds "10KB" and delete the old ones when the total file count exceeds "5". This actually works when I test it within the same day;
[image]

However, I want these rules still apply when I have log files from previous days but this is not working;
[image]

As it can be seen from the above image, it does not delete the logs files from previous days and only applies the rules to current day's log files.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `periodic-size-rotating-file-handler` does not delete files rotated by the date. From a snippet of the `read-resource-description` operation:

```
"result" => [{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "logging"),
        ("periodic-size-rotating-file-handler" => "*")
    ],
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "description" => "Defines a handler which writes to a file, rotating the log after a time 
            period derived from the given suffix string or after the size of the file grows beyond a 
            certain point and keeping a fixed number of backups. The suffix should be in a format 
            understood by the java.text.SimpleDateFormat. Any backups rotated by the suffix will not be purged during a size rotation.",
        "capabilities" => [{
            "name" => "org.wildfly.logging.handler",
            "dynamic" => true,
            "dynamic-elements" => ["periodic-size-rotating-file-handler"]
        }],
```

The last part of the description talks about this:

> Any backups rotated by the suffix will not be purged during a size rotation.

There is a long standing [issue](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/LOGMGR-57) for this that I should really find the time to work on at some point. Unfortunately for now though something like a cron job is the only way.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll be following the issue.